# How to get column names WebMatrix.Data

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, webmatrix

Trying to figure out how to get the column names from the SQL statement. Saw something online that says this works, but surely it doesn't:

```
 var rows=db.Query("select * from users");

 <ul>
     @foreach(var col in rows)
     {
         <li>@col.name</li>
     }
 </ul>
```

This displays the value only if there is a column with the name `name`, but I'd like the actual column name if possible.

Anyone know how to get all the column names using WebMatrix.Data ?

EDIT:

Looks like the `DynamicRecord` Class exposes the column names, just wondering how it applies.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.data.dynamicrecord(v=vs.111).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok let me explain this for you.

I have created a new project and tested it in the Visual Studio and it works. You need to udnerstand the basics about the DynamicRecord and the property of the Columns.

Here is the code that I have used,

```
@{ 
    var db = Database.Open("StarterSite");
    var selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM UserProfile";
    var result = db.Query(selectQuery);
}
```

In the HTML I did this,

```
<div>
    @foreach (var row in result)
    {
        <p>@row.Columns[0]</p>
    }
</div>
```

When it executed, since the `DynamicRecord.Columns` property is an `IList<string>` generic type, so you should understand that you can read their properties through a simple indexation. Like the one I have done, it will read the first column from the List of the strings that was sent down to the user.

Now when it executed, since the very first column was *Email*, it gave me the following output on screen.

[image]

You can get others from the list too. Just update the index number. :-)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.data.dynamicrecord.columns(v=vs.111).aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [GetDynamicMemberNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicmetaobject.getdynamicmembernames(v=vs.110).aspx) method to obtain the "columns" (which have been converted to dynamic properties)

```
var rows = db.Query("select * from users");

 <ul>
     @foreach(var item in rows.First().GetDynamicMemberNames())
     {
         <li>row[item]</li>
     }
 </ul>
```

Comment: How do you accomplish this? I get the error `'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<dynamic>' does not contain a definition for 'GetDynamicMemberNames'...` I tried adding System.Linq and System.Dynamic, but I still get that error.

Comment: @TravisHeeter The code sample was incorrect. I've updated it now to use the First() method to get the first element in the sequence. GetDynamicMemberNames works on a dynamic type, not a collection as your error message points out.